# Need help to add a constraint to a MIP model in R

Tags: r, mathematical-optimization, linear-programming, ompr

I'm trying to build a model to optimize steel production. The objective is to reduce the amount of waste (leftover material after the steel has been cut). The code below is what I have so far. It is lacking a constraint to make sure that each item in work_tbl is fulfilled from a single item in inventory_tbl (but several items from work_tbl can be fulfilled by one item in inventory_tbl, given that there is enough length available).

code/reproducible example:

```
# Load required packages
library(dplyr)
library(ompr)
library(ompr.roi)
library(ROI)


# Define the problem data
work_tbl <- data.frame(length = c(2500, 500, 700, 1200, 1500, 2000, 2500, 3000, 4000, 5250))
inventory_tbl <-
  data.frame(length = c(1300, 2000, 1800, 2600, 3000, 2000, 5000, 6000, 7000, 9000, 2000, 500, 4000, 12000, 7400, 13000))

# Define variables to be used 

work_count <- nrow(work_tbl)
invent_count <- nrow(inventory_tbl)
big_M <- sum(work_tbl$length) * 1.1

# Initialize the model

steel_model <- ompr::MIPModel() %>% 
  
  # Binary decision variable - steel to be cut
  add_variable(steel_cut[work, inventory],
               work = 1:work_count,
               inventory = 1:invent_count,
               type = "binary") %>% 
  
  # Binary decision variable: Take new item from inventory?
  add_variable(take_item[inventory],
               inventory = 1:invent_count,
               type = "binary") %>% 
  
  # Constraint 1: Each item in work_tbl must be cut
  add_constraint(sum_over(steel_cut[work, inventory],
                          inventory = 1:invent_count) == 1,
                 work = 1:work_count)  %>% 
  
  # Constraint 2: The sum of each item used to cut from needs to be equal to or smaller than the work item
  add_constraint(sum_over(steel_cut[work, inventory] * work_tbl$length[work],
                          work = 1:work_count) <= inventory_tbl$length[inventory],
                 inventory = 1:invent_count, work = 1:work_count) %>% 
  
  # Constraint 3: big_M constraint to activate take_item whenever a length is cut
  add_constraint(
    sum_over(steel_cut[work, inventory],
             work = 1:work_count) <= big_M * take_item[inventory],
    inventory = 1:invent_count
  ) %>% 
  
  # Set objective function to minimize scrap / waste 
  set_objective(
    sum_over(
      take_item[inventory] * inventory_tbl$length[inventory],
      inventory = 1:invent_count
    ) - sum_over(steel_cut[work, inventory] * work_tbl$length[work],
                 work = 1:work_count,
                 inventory = 1:invent_count), sense = "min"
  )

# View the model
steel_model

# Solve the model

solution <- ompr::solve_model(steel_model, with_ROI(solver = "glpk", verbose = TRUE))  

# Check objective value
solution$objective_value

# Get the solution 
steel_model_soln <-
  ompr::get_solution(solution, steel_cut[work, inventory]) %>% filter(value > 0) %>% 
  mutate(cut_length = work_tbl$length[work])

# View the solution
steel_model_soln
```

Comment: Some vocabulary will help you greatly!  This is called a "cutting stock" problem in linear programming and is VERY common.  There are many examples on this site, some of which are in `r`: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=cutting+stock+%5Br%5D

Comment: I would think the only variable you need is a binary one, call it `take` or something that denotes that you are taking piece `i` from stock piece `j` ... `take[i, j]`  like your `cut_order` variable, but just make it binary...  then you can multiply it by the lengths of the orders or stock as needed to make your constraints

Comment: @AirSquid Thanks for the vocabulary. Unfortunately, very few of the results from your query is actually about the problem, and none of them uses the ompr package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My `r` syntax is pretty rusty, but...  Your model is close.  Why don't you:

1. Change `cut_order` to a **binary** variable, indicating that you are cutting `work` from `inventory`.
2. 'take_item' looks good as a binary also...leave it.
3. Change constraint 1 to a loop because you need a "for each work item"....  You need a summation constraint *for each item* in `work`.  It is minimization, so don't fret the `>=`.  In pseudocode:

```
for each work:
    add_constraint(sum(cut_order[work, inventory] over inventory) >= 1)
```

4. change constraint 2 to loop over each `inventory` to again create a constraint "for each" inventory piece and multiply the selection variable by the work length in the constraint

```
for each inventory:
    add_constraint(sum(cut_order[work, inventory]*work_length[work]) <= inventory_length[inventory])
```

5. Constraint 3 looks good
6. Change your objective to accumulate the scrap...

```
sum(take_item[inventory]*inventory_length[inventory] - sum(cut_order[work, inventory]*work_length[work] over work) over inventory)
```

Another alternative that you might consider is just minimizing(take_item) to use the minimal number of sticks consumed, or penalizing slightly with a weight the use of longer sticks, to help consume the short stuff first, etc.  All that is gravy after you get the model breathing...

##### Edit:  An (untested) stab at the `r` code:

```
# Load libraries

# Load required packages
library(dplyr)
library(ompr)
library(ompr.roi)
library(ROI)


# Define the problem data
work_tbl <- data.frame(length = c(2500, 500, 700))
inventory_tbl <-
  data.frame(length = c(1300, 2000, 1800, 2600, 3000))

work_count <- nrow(work_tbl)
invent_count <- nrow(inventory_tbl)
big_M <- (work_tbl$length) * 1.1

# initialize the model

steel_model <- ompr::MIPModel() %>% 
  
  # How much steel to be cut for each item
  add_variable(steel_cut[work, inventory],
               work = 1:work_count,
               inventory = 1:invent_count,
               type = "binary") %>% 
  
  # Take new item from inventory?
  add_variable(take_item[inventory],
               inventory = 1:invent_count,
               type = "binary") %>% 
  
  # Constraint 1: each work item must be fulfilled
  # You need to make a sum over all work FOR EACH inventory item, so inventory should be outside the sum
  add_constraint(sum_over(steel_cut[work, inventory], inventory = 1:invent_count ) == 1,
                work = 1:work_count)  %>% 
  
  # Constraint 2: for each item, ensure lengths cut is less than or equal to length of item
  # Again, here the summation of stuff used is compared to EACH inventory item, so that
  # needs to be outside the summation, but WORK is alread summed inside and should not be included...
  # you are basically saying, for each inventory item, sum up all of the work assigned to it and compare it
  # to the length of that inventory item
  add_constraint(sum_over(steel_cut[work, inventory] * work_tbl$length[work], work = 1:work_count) <= inventory_tbl$length[inventory],
                inventory = 1:invent_count) %>% 

  
  # Constraint 3: big_M to activate take_item whenever a length is cut
  add_constraint(sum_over(steel_cut[work, inventory], work = 1:work_count) <= big_M * take_item[inventory],
                inventory = 1:invent_count) %>% 
  
  # needed to multiply the steel_cut selection variable by the length of the work
  set_objective(sum_over(take_item[inventory] * inventory_tbl$length[inventory], inventory = 1:invent_count) 
              - sum_over(steel_cut[work, inventory] * work_tbl$length[work], work = 1:work_count, inventory = 1:invent_count), sense = "min")

steel_model

solution <- ompr::solve_model(steel_model, with_ROI(solver = "glpk", verbose = TRUE))  

solution$objective_value

steel_model_soln <-
  ompr::get_solution(solution, steel_cut[work, inventory]) %>% filter(value > 0)
```

Comment: Hi - thanks. I'll give that a whirl. One question - when `cut_order`is binary, there isn't a continuous variable to minimize, so I'm guessing that in your example, work_length and inventory_length would be the length column of the respective tables? 

I might be off, but is the loop really necessary? This code:

`sum_over(cut_order[work, inventory],work = 1:work_count) <= inventory_tbl$length[inventory], inventory = 1:invent_count
  )`

essentially does that?

Comment: first part:  yes, the `work_length` and `inventory_length` are the fixed (parameter) values from your tables.  You do not need a a continuous variable here, if you stubby-pencil a couple examples for the objective function, you will see that the use of the binaries * the lengths is "totalling up" the selections.

Comment: Second, yeah, the loop is necessary.  Any time you have a "for each" constraint, a set of constraints need to be generated.  You have 2 such instances.  For the first, you are saying "for each work order" ... it must be cut from at least one inventory.

Comment: I'm not sure that is the case, I have other models with similar problems, and it works without any for loops in those. I'm not able to get the pseudo-code working, but thanks for the help :)

Comment: Ahhh….  Well, you definitely need to make a constraint for each item of `work` in Constraint 1, etc.  But after looking at it again, I think I misread the `r` syntax and you are in fact already doing that within the `add_constraint()` call.  So, I think the “loop” I mentioned in pseudocode is already rolled up in that.  So, aside from that, what isn’t working?

Comment: It's working in the sense that it cuts the first piece from the right item (if the first item has a length of 2500, it correctly chooses the third piece to match it to), but it's only matches the first item in the work_tbl.

Comment: Hmmm...  could you edit your original post and just augment it with the edited version of your code in entirety to take a look?  After deducing what is going on with the `add_constraint()` syntax, it is quite readable.

Comment: Sure, it's edited now :)

Comment: take a look at my edit and comments, you had a small error in both C1 and C2 that I think I got and commented.  LMK if the code comments aren't clear

Comment: The code runs with a small correction where [work] was not defined, but the status of the model is `LP HAS NO PRIMAL FEASIBLE SOLUTION` so the constraints are too strict.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253293/discussion-between-airsquid-and-regressionsquirrel).

Comment: Using the updated first post (which now works thanks to @airsquid), I've tried to expand on this to include another dimension, but so far I've been unsuccessful. 

Let's say there are different types of steel, exemplified by the following: 

`work_tbl <- data.frame(
  length = c(2500, 500, 700, 1200, 1500, 2000, 2500, 3000, 4000, 5250),
  type = sample(c('Type A', 'Type B'), 10, replace=TRUE)`

I've tried to recode the type as a integer variable (in reality, there are more than just two types, so binary does not work). Any tips on how to add this as a constraint?